# align image and text side by side and setting the text max height to img hieght

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, css-grid

I cant figure out how to position 3 elements inside a div container(css grid), and keep the page responsive.

1. title(purple in the img)
2. photo
3. comments(green in the img)

[the flow i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEwyz.jpg)

the problem is, if i change the window size, the comments section do not overflow, instead its in-large the div container.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk8JD.png)

instad its need to look like this :
[the right way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObCp8.jpg)

i succeeded to achieve that with max-height: and overflow:scroll, but i believe there must be an easier way(for the max-height part, of course), and more practical.

```css
.post-container {
  background-color: rgb(0, 224, 255);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'title title' 'photo comments';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Title {
  background-color: rgb(47, 0, 99);
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: title;
  color: white;
}

.Photo {
  grid-area: photo;
}

.Comments {
  background-color: rgb(11, 75, 82);
  grid-area: comments;
  color: white
}

.post-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="post-container">
    <div class="Title">
      <h1>comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit? </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="Photo">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1210543/pexels-photo-1210543.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=architecture-bay-blue-1210543.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="Comments">
      <ul>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to set the row's `height`, the other content(`ul`) needs to be taken of the flow via `position:absolute;`.

You need also to set the width of this area via a template `grid-template-colums`.

Once this area(`.Comments`) has a `width`(from template) and an `height`(from img), set it in `position:relative;` and size the `ul` via coordonates. Overflow will come next.

demo below of the idea to avoid ul to resize your grid

```css
.post-container {
  background-color: rgb(0, 224, 255);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas: 'title title' 'photo comments';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Title {
  background-color: rgb(47, 0, 99);
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: title;
  color: white;
}

.Photo {
  grid-area: photo;
}

.Photo img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.Comments {
  background-color: rgb(11, 75, 82);
  grid-area: comments;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.Comments ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.post-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="post-container">
    <div class="Title">
      <h1>comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit? </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="Photo">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1210543/pexels-photo-1210543.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=architecture-bay-blue-1210543.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="Comments">
      <ul>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
        <li>comment comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit?</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank u very much for your answer:)
but there one thing i still don't get, why the .Comments part is little bit bigger then .Photo?
i tried to set margin to 0 and padding also, but still no luck...

Comment: @mewmewimacow it is about the fact that img is an inline-block standing on the baseline (underneath there is a little gap to leave room for letters such as  j,p,q ..) You reset the vertical-align property to top or bottom or reset display to block. snippet's answer updated with vertical-align.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div>
<div style="float:left"></div>
<div style="float:right"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

without testing, should be something like this. one div that have all inside, the second dont have absolute certain is a block, e other two must be side by side.

you can put the style i have i my div  in your class of course.